# Undefined property when accessing Vue datas

Tags: vue.js

so im still learning on Vue.js. and i tried to make the course on my own. i have made 2 new components for this course. Quote.vue and Progress.vue. When i tried to access {this.Progress} on Progress.vue method inside the created(), it will affect the data of that file. But why when i tried to access {this.Quotes} on App.Vue, it returns undefined?

App.Vue :

```
import {eventBus} from "../src/main";
    import Quote from "../src/components/Quote.vue"
    import Progress from "../src/components/Progress.vue";
    export default {
        data: function(){
            return {
                QuoteInput: "",
                Id: 1,
                Quotes:[]
            }
        },
        created(){
            eventBus.$on("removeChild",function(x){
                debugger;
                console.log(this.Id) // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
                console.log(this.Quotes) // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
                eventBus.$emit("quoteRemoved");
            });
        },
        components:{
            "progress-bar":Progress,
            "quote-holder":Quote
        }, 
        methods:{
            AddQuote(){
                this.Quotes.push({Quote:this.QuoteInput, QuoteId:this.Id})
                this.Id++;  
                eventBus.$emit("quoteAdded");
            }
        }        
    }
```

Progress.Vue

```
<script>
import {eventBus} from "../main"
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {
            progress: 0
        }
    },
    created(){
        eventBus.$on("quoteAdded",(x)=>{
            if(this.progress === 100){
                alert("Too much buddy");
            }else{
                this.progress += 10; // THIS WORKS 
            }
        });

        eventBus.$on("quoteRemoved",(x)=>{
            if(this.progress === 0){
                alert("What do you want to delete? its empty");
            }else{
                this.progress -= 10;
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: in App.vue try `eventBus.$on("removeChild",(x)=>{`

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

`function(x){}` -> `(x) => {}`

```js
      created(){
            eventBus.$on("removeChild",(x)=>{
                debugger;
                console.log(this.Id) // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
                console.log(this.Quotes) // THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
                eventBus.$emit("quoteRemoved");
            });
        },
```